# NGINX [emerg] unknown directive "upload_pass" error in a config file

Tags: nginx, passenger

I have installed Nginx 1.2.0 with Passenger on my Mac Mini running Lion Server. I used the instructions from the link below.

https://github.com/coverall/nginx

I will state upfront that I am new to Nginx & Passenger.  I am working on a Ruby on Rails project that I would like to host on the server.  When I try to start Nginx I get the following error:

```
[emerg] unknown directive "upload_pass" in /usr/local/etc/nginx/virtualhosts/adam.localhost.coverallcrew.com.conf:20
```

Here are lines 19 & 20 from the file in question.  This is a file that I assume was included in the Nginx installation.  The only config file I have done anything with is nginx.conf where I added the lines to hopefully host my Rails application.

```
# pass request body to here
upload_pass @fast_upload_endpoint;
```

This is my second attempt at doing extensive web searches on how to correct this error.  I had hoped to find if I needed to add something to nginx.conf or something to get upload_pass defined somewhere but only found solutions where the directive was indeed missing.

I took a look at nginx.conf.  There are a lot of statements commented out.  Here are the ones that are not:

```
http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile        on;
    gzip  on;
    server_name_in_redirect off;
    port_in_redirect off;

    client_max_body_size 8m;
    client_body_buffer_size 128k;

    include upstreams/*.conf;
    include virtualhosts/*.conf;
    include third-party/*.conf;

    server {
        listen 8080;
        server_name www.lightbesandbox2.com;
        root /Sites/iktusnetlive_ror/public;
        passenger_enabled on;
    }
}
```

Another question: Do I need these virtual hosts that were including in the Nginx install?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears your Nginx is not compiled with the [upload_pass](http://www.grid.net.ru/nginx/upload.en.html) module so it does not understand that directive. I am not certain how to do this with homebrew, but you can compile it in:

`./configure --add-module=/path/to/upload_pass/source`

Comment: I ended up having other problems with Nginx. I decided to delete this installation and install another version of Nginx without all the bells & whistles in the link I included here.  So far I have been able to get Nginx & Passenger to launch without any errors.  Thanks for your input.  I will save your answer if I run into this problem again.